# How do I search for an integer array in a cell array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a cell array containing an array of integer arrays. What is the best way to search the cell array for a specific array and return true if it exists and false otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` combined with `isequal`:

For example:

```
cellArr = {[1 2 3],'xcxc',magic(5),1:3};
element = [1 2 3];
indexes = cellfun( @(x)isequal(x,element),cellArr);
```

This will give you an array that contains `true` in the cells that the element exists.
In order to check whether the element exists at least once, just use:

```
any(indexes)
```